# Highcharts Gauge Chart with text labels

Tags: highcharts

i have a gauge charts with defined tick positions and want to show some text labels there. e. g.:

- -300 => Text 1
- -200 => Text 2
- -100 => Text 3
- ...

Is there a way to do that? Here's a fiddle of the chart.

[jsfiddle.net/r8d3jnx6/](http://jsfiddle.net/r8d3jnx6/)

```
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'gauge',
                alignTicks: false,
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBackgroundImage: null,
                plotBorderWidth: 0,
                plotShadow: false
            },

            title: {
                text: null
            },

            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },

            pane: {
                startAngle: -70,
                endAngle: 70,
                background: null
            },

            plotOptions: {
                gauge: {
                    dial: {
                        baseWidth: 2,
                        baseLength: '100%',
                        radius: '100%',
                        rearLength: 0
                    },
                    pivot: {
                        radius: 5
                    },
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },

            yAxis: [ {
                min: -300,
                max: 500,
                tickPositions: [-300, -200, -100, 0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
                lineColor: '#933',
                lineWidth: 0,
                minorTickPosition: 'outside',
                tickLength: 0,
                minorTickLength: 0,
                labels: {
                    distance: 12,
                    //rotation: 'auto'
                },
                //categories: ['Grunder'],
                offset: 0,
                plotBands: [{
                    from: -300,
                    to: 2,
                    thickness: 15,
                    color: '#55BF3B'
                }, {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 202,
                    thickness: 15,
                    color: {
                        linearGradient: {x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 0},
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#55BF3B'], //green
                            [1, '#DDDF0D'] //yellow
                        ]
                    }
                }, {
                    from: 200,
                    to: 500,
                    thickness: 15,
                    color: {
                        linearGradient: {x1: 0, x2: 1, y1: 0, y2: 0},
                        stops: [
                            [0, '#DDDF0D'], //yellow
                            [1, '#ff0000'] //red
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                min: -200,
                max: 200,
                lineColor: '#339',
                tickColor: '#339',
                minorTickColor: '#339',
                offset: -100,
                lineWidth: 2,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tickLength: 5,
                minorTickLength: 5,
                endOnTick: false
            }],

            series: [{
                data: [250]
            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `yAxis.labels.formatter` function to check what the label value is, and return a text of your choice depending on that value.

To take your example, it could look like this:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            if(this.value == -300) return '-300 => Text 1';
            if(this.value == -200) return '-200 => Text 2';
            if(this.value == -100) return '-100 => Text 3';
            return this.value;
    }
}
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8d3jnx6/1/) of how it works. As you can see you'll have to face the potential issue of labels overlapping the gauge, but you can fix that with `distance`, `rotation` and some other attributes ([see API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels)), depending on how your labels end up looking.

Comment: It's not the most elegant solution, but i think it's the only one :) Thanks!